# prove that the maximal torus of $SO(3)$ is the maximal torus of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: group-theory, matrices, lie-groups

I want to prove that the maximal torus of $SO(3)$ is the maximal torus of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$. I want to use the theorem that every maximal torus of G equals $gTg^{-1}$ for some $g \in G$. But I am not sure how the argument can be made. I was trying to think of it in terms of how reflections can map on to the lines. And how for every rotation there can be a line associated with it, since every element of $SO(3)$ can be achieved by starting with the identity position and rotating by some angle.

I would really appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific maximal torus in mind? Maximal tori are only unique up to conjugation. Or is the question "prove that a maximal torus of SO(3) is also a maximal torus of $GL_{3}(\mathbb{R})$"?

Comment: I think you should for clarity specify "compact torus". In (non compact) Lie group theory, the term is also used to refer to products that may involve, apart from circle groups, multiplicative groups of the complex or real numbers. In particular a maximal torus in $GL(3,\Bbb R)$ could then be the set of diagonal matrices, which is not compact.

Comment: I agree with Marc. In my answer, I assumed by maximal torus of $GL_{3}(\mathbb{R})$, you meant a maximal compact, connected abelian group. But there are larger, connected abelian subgroups (in particular, the subgroup of diagonal matrices with positive terms.) In fact, often, the term maximal torus merely refers to the subgroup corresponding to the Cartan subalgebra in the Lie algebra, which would be the diagonal positive matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the two main ideas are that any compact, connected subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is actually contained in a subgroup isomorphic to $SO(3)$ and that maximal tori in compact groups are conjugate.

Let $G$ be a compact subgroup of $GL_{3}(\mathbb{R})$. Take an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Then, we can make it $G$ invariant by averaging over the Haar measure of $G$. Thus, if we take $H$ to be the copy of $O(3)$ defined by this inner product, then $G$ is a subgroup of $H$. In addition, if $G$ is connected, then it is a subgroup of $H^{0}$ which is isomorphic to $SO(3)$.

Now, let $T$ be a maximal torus of $GL_{3}$ and, since it is compact and connected, pick some $H \cong SO(3)$ that contains $T$. Let $B$ be the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and let $B'$ be the inner product determining $H$ (so basically choose two bases $\{e_{1}, \ldots, e_{n}\}$ and $\{v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}\}$ which are oriented, orthonormal bases for the respective inner product.) Let $M$ be the matrix (in the standard basis) that takes $e_{i}$ to $v_{i}$, and hence has $v_{i}$ for the $i$th column. The claim is then,
$$MSO(3)M^{-1} = H$$
where $SO(3)$ here is the standard $SO(3)$. For the proof, if $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$,and $N \in SO(3)$, we have
$$B'(Mv, Mw) = B(v, w)$$
and hence,
$$B'(MNM^{-1} v, MNM^{-1}w) = B(NM^{-1}v, NM^{-1}w) = B(M^{-1}v, M^{-1}w) = B'(v, w).$$

So, we see that $M^{-1}TM \subseteq SO(3)$. In particular, this means that $M^{-1}TM$ is a compact, connected, abelian subgroup of $SO(3)$, and must be maximal with respect to such properties, because if there were a bigger such subgroup of $SO(3)$, then this would also be a bigger such subgroup of $GL_{3}(\mathbb{R})$, which would contradict the fact that $T$ is a maximal torus of $GL_{3}$. Hence, $M^{-1}TM$ is a maximal torus of $SO(3)$.

Now, if $S$ is an arbitrary maximal torus of $SO(3)$, it will be conjugate to $M^{-1}TM$ (because all maximal tori of compact groups are conjugate), and hence will be conjugate in $GL_{3}$ to $T$. Hence, $S$ will also be a maximal torus of $GL_{3}(\mathbb{R}$).